# Read Excel file without signature in PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

**Question: how does one read or modify an Excel file without signature to allow PHP to parse it properly?**

For my project, I want to automatically download and read an [Excel file](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0NGsJS_iDppRHBjeTk0bGh4MmM) from the national volleyball association (Nevobo) using PHP. Downloading goes fine. Reading does not. The issue seems to be related to the fact that there's no signature in the first 8 bytes that tell PHPExcel that it is an OLE file, as such PHPExcel identifies it as a CSV file, which it definitely is not. Excel itself can open the file but will force me to save it in a [different format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6snaE.png).

I have previously downloaded files from the same source (different content though), which also lack the signature. However on these files I have managed to filter all the control characters (`\x00` thru `\xFF`) in PHP and automatically create a new row when it sees a date (since those are all in column A), unfortunately that didn't work with this file.

```
function cleanPart ( $part )
{
    $part = trim(preg_replace('/[\x00\x01\x03-\x0A\x0D-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', trim($part, ' ')), ' ');
    $part = preg_replace('/\x0B/', "\x0C", $part);
    $part = preg_replace('/\"/', "\x0C", $part);
    $part = preg_replace('/\x0C+/', "\x0C", $part);
    $part = preg_replace('/\x0C\x02/', "\x0C", $part);
    if ( $part == "\x02\x0C" || $part == "\x02\x0B" ) return false;
    $part = trim(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', "\x02", $part), ' ');
    $part = trim(preg_replace('/\x02+/', "\x02", $part), ' ');
    $part = trim(preg_replace('/[\x00\x01\x03-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $part), ' ');
    if ( strlen($part) == 0 ) return false;
    $part = trim(preg_replace('/\x02/', "", $part), ' ');

    return $part;
}

foreach ( explode("\x04", preg_replace('!\x04+!', "\x04", $data)) as $part )
{
    if ( ! ( $part = cleanPart($part) ) )
    {
        continue;
    }

    // create array
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: You are downloading an csv file with xlsx extension. Fastest way to build an excel from html without using server side scripting. What's wrong with a csv? You can parse it in php without phpexcel! It is even easier for you!

Comment: The file certainly doesn't have a Excel signature, but I've no idea what it actually is

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited my post to reflect the code attempts I have made at parsing this file. I have also done a lot of googling for unix excel repair scripts but without any success. There's a site that lets you upload the file and it repairs it for you but there's no advantage over opening it in Excel and resaving it.

Comment: [Marco Pontello's identifier](http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx) suggests with 100.0% certainty that it's a 100,0% Targa bitmap (Original TGA Format)?!?

Comment: @LelioFaieta it's not a CSV though, there's no common delimiter (such as a comma or tab) between any of the fields [screenshot of UTF-8 encoding](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnr3u.png)

Comment: @MarkBaker I can tell you with 100% certainty it's supposed to be an Excel file [downloaded by clicking the "Exporteer Excel" button](http://i.imgur.com/2K4RdJv.png)

Comment: Like I say, the signature bears no resemblance to that of an Excel file (either BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format).... and Marco's online identifier certainly doesn't see it as any known Excel format.... just because a file claims to be Excel, doesn't mean that it actually is an Excel file, there's thousands of websites that offer an Excel download, but give csv or html markup.... perhaps you could ask the owners/developers of the site what format it actually is, but it certainly isn't recognised as an Excel format file

Comment: @MarkBaker while I definitely agree with your point about the signature, the [file successfully opens in Excel](http://i.imgur.com/fOjtLxx.png). As you suggested, I have contacted the owners of the site to fix this issue. Although I believe if Excel can read a file that is not supposed to be an Excel file (nor does it look anything like csv or html), something else should as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibreOffice does read the file as an Excel file, so this *must* be a known format by LibreOffice, even if `file magic` identifies it as Apple BASIC (!) and other utilities as TARGA (which means little more than "binary data with length multiple of three").

However, **this is a delimited text format**. Possibly it is a word processor format and the strange characters are control characters for tabulation and typefacing?

To convert more reliably in a CSV type, you can replace all control sequences with tabulations, skipping the first 12 characters. All control sequences appear to also be 12 bytes long, prefixed by \x04 \x02, so:

```
$clean = preg_replace('#\\x04\\x02..........#ms', "\t", substr($dirty, 24));
```

(I have skipped the first control sequence too, giving 12+12 = 24 byte skip).

You can then split into field chunks, then PHP CSV parse functions should be able to work, 20 fields per row.

I cannot use CSV parse using the sequences as delimiter because the sequences are different throughout the file. Also they often include carriage returns, which forces to use the whitespace/line modifier in the regex.

This parser appears to work:

```
<?php
$clean = preg_split(
    '#\\x04\\x02..........#ms',
    substr(file_get_contents('excelgen.xls'), 24)
);
$rows  = array();
while (!empty($clean)) {
    $rows[]   = array_splice($clean, 0, 20);
}
// $header = array_shift($rows);
print_r($rows);
```

yields:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Datum
        [1] => Tijd
        [2] => Team thuis
        [3] => Team uit
        [4] => Locatie
        [5] => Veld
        [6] => Regio
        [7] => Poule
        [8] => Code
        [9] => Zaal code
        [10] => Zaal
        [11] => Plaats
        [12] => Eerste scheidsrechter
        [13] => Tweede scheidsrechter
        [14] => Rapporteur / begeleider / Jurylid
        [15] => Lijnrechter 1
        [16] => Lijnrechter 2
        [17] => Lijnrechter 3
        [18] => Lijnrechter 4
        [19] => Reserve
...
...
[54] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2016-04-23
        [1] => 19:30
        [2] => Ecare Apollo 8 HS 1
        [3] => Lycurgus HS 2
        [4] => de Veste, Borne
        [5] => 1
        [6] => Nationaal
        [7] => 1AH
        [8] => AL
        [9] => BNEVE
        [10] => de Veste
        [11] => Borne
        ...
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, it never occurred to me that there were 12 bytes of control characters between each column as I had always been more focussed on finding a pattern in a specific control character. It seems that in every last column, it repeats `\x04 \x02 \x12` but unfortunately this occurs at some other points as well, this is definitely an excellent starting point. Thanks again!